# How do I make an php array json encode with all values that i have in my sql table

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have an ajax code to make an table with the results that i should receive from my php table, but my php its not working.
I must receive an a json encode from php with all arrays that i have in mysql.

Here's my ajax code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'financeiro/cpg/tabela.php',
      success: function(data)
      {
      console.log(data);
        createTableByJqueryEach(data);
      },
      async:   true,
      dataType: 'json'
    }); 

});

function createTableByJqueryEach(data)
{


  var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th>Nome</th><th>Valor</th><th>Porque?</th><th>Data</th><th>Data de Vencimento</th><th>Produtos/Serviço</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
  $.each(data,function(index, row){

    eTable += "<tr>";
    $.each(row,function(key,value){
      eTable += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
    });
    eTable += "</tr>";
  });
  eTable +="</tbody></table>";
  $('#Tabela').html(eTable);
}
```

My not functional php code

```
<?php include_once("../../../config.php");
$rows = array();
$sql= "SELECT * FROM cpg"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;

    echo json_encode($rows); } ?>
```

Comment: What's not functional about it? Are you getting errors? What does console.log(data) return?

Comment: Console don't show anything

Comment: there's a trailing additional `}` in your shown code, so I suppose there's some more code that isn't shown here. Otherwise this would throw an error.

Comment: The concept looks correct. As we cannot debug your code (is the db-connection ok, is the sql ok, is there a result, etc.) we cannot really answer/help.

Comment: As Jeff noted, remove the extra } in the tabela.php file ( json_encode($rows); } <~that).. and if that doesn't work, try debugging the tabela.php by accessing it directly  to see if you are getting a result for $rows.

Comment: I already remove the old brace and add a line with an a array and still don't get the values

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove that extra closing brace:

```
<?php include_once("../../../config.php");

$sql= "SELECT * FROM cpg"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows); **}** ?>
```

Comment: I'm still don't get the results in an array

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you access the tabela.php file directly?

PS.. you don't/shouldn't need the `$rows = array();` or `$rows[] = $row;`
AND, try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` (mysqli_fetch_array will just duplicate the results, meaning you will get the `column number:value` AND the `column name:value`)

```
<?php include_once("../../../config.php");

$sql= "SELECT * FROM cpg"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo json_encode($row); 
}
?>
```